# Magento : Translate theme to my language

Tags: magento, translate

I want to translate theme to my language.I searched about it and some one suggested that in     " app/design/fronted/default/theme-folder " create locale folder and in this folder create for example en_US folder and in this create translate.csv for translate theme file to language that wanted. I do this solution but it doesn't worked!!! 
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create translate you need to follow below steps :

Place your language package in `/app/locale` directory.

Now got to `Admin c-panel > System > Configuration > General > Locale Options > Locale` select you language pack from the Dropdown list.

[image]

Comment: It set to my language but theme have some word that they didn't translate, if i want to translate them i should add these word to app/locale/my-lang/translate.csv ???

Comment: yes you need to add these word in translate.csv file.

Comment: you can also translate the words through Inline. Go to System > configuration > Developers > Translate Inline. After enabling this you can translate directly through UI